# How to scan for application options in OSX

Tags: macos

I occasionally see howtos that allow you to change the functionality of some applications on OSX using `defaults` in the command line. I know that people find these configuration directives through scanning the application. How is that done?

fix: could have sworn it was `option`. My bad.

Comment: Do you mean `defaults`?

Comment: Are you talking about graphical applications or UNIX applications?

Comment: Graphical / .app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `defaults` to not only change these values, but also to list them.

`defaults read -g` show "global" options, while `defaults read com.company.ProgramName` show the *defaults* (i.e. configuration options) for a particular program. In this context, `com.company.ProgramName` is the *bundle identifier* of the program, e.g. `com.apple.TextEdit` or `com.culturedcode.Things`. [More on this](https://superuser.com/questions/200167/what-does-com-developer-application-mean/200205#200205).

---

For example, run `defaults read com.apple.Finder` and you will find a line that says `AppleShowAllFiles = FALSE` or something similar. Now be adventurous and run `defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean TRUE` and restart Finder to see what happens.

For more information how to use `defaults`, enter `man defaults` to view its documentation. It can become quite complex, and some things related to lists and dictionaries are pretty much impossible to do. Once you get that far, look up `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` -- there are some examples how to use it on this site, just use the search function.

---

[Find out a particular program's bundle identifier](https://superuser.com/questions/200167/what-does-com-developer-application-mean/200205#200205):

> To find out what your application uses for *com.vendor.yourapp*, right-click the application bundle, select *Show Package Contents*, navigate to *Contents*, open *Info.plist* using a text editor, or better a property list editor like *Property List Editor* or *Xcode 4* (both part of Apple's developer tools) and look for *CFBundleIdentifier* or the like.

---

Another tool you can use is `strings`. It will display all strings (i.e. possibly useful sequences of characters) in a binary file. Note that this yields *tons* of false positives, since Objective-C function calls are also shown, as well as regular output that is shown on the UI.

---

[Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com/) also offers a database of hidden settings for OS X, sorted by application. These can be changed by using `defaults`. For your convenience, you can also download a Preference Pane from the website, which allows you to change these over your System Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

# find key names in ~/Library/Preferences/`osascript -e 'id of app "iTunes"'`.plist
defaults read com.apple.iTunes | ruby -e 'puts STDIN.read.scan(/^    \"?([a-zA-Z_.\-]+?)\"? /)' > keys.txt

# extract identifiers from a binary
# (the output is tens of thousands of lines even after grepping)
strings - /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes | egrep "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_.\-]{7,}$" | ruby -e 'puts STDIN.read.split("\n").uniq' > strings.txt

# the identifiers for preferences often appear near each other
for x in `cat /0/keys.txt`; do
    grep -C 10 "$x" strings.txt
done | ruby -e 'puts STDIN.read.split("\n").uniq' > strings2.txt
```

---

Another method using the GNU debugger: [arcticmac.home.comcast.net/~arcticmac/tutorials/gdbFindingPrefs.html](http://arcticmac.home.comcast.net/~arcticmac/tutorials/gdbFindingPrefs.html)